# Force TinyMCE to strip out data- attributes

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-3

I'm using the TinyMCE plugin and have the `valid_elements` option is set to:

```
"a[href|target:_blank],strong/b,em/i,br,p,ul,ol,li"
```

Even though data- attributes aren't listed, TinyMCE doesn't strip them out.  It seems to strip out all other non-listed attributes, but for some reason, data- attributes (e.g. `data-foo="bar"`) are an exception.  How can I get TinyMCE to strip out data- attributes?

I'm using TinyMCE version 3.4.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem.  I manually changed the HTML that TinyMCE produces by running it through this function:

```
var stripDataAttributes = function(html) {

  var tags = html.match(/(<\/?[\S][^>]*>)/gi);
  tags.forEach(function(tag){
    html = html.replace(tag, tag.replace(/(data-.+?=".*?")|(data-.+?='.*?')|(data-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/g, ''));
  });

  return html;
};
```

Here's a jsbin for it: https://jsbin.com/lavemi/3/edit?js,console

Here's how you can use it:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(
  stripDataAttributes(
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()
  )
);
```

Comment: I have to ask, if 5 years later this is the best way, because I'm having the exact same issue with TinyMCE 5, specifically inside List Items when copied from Word

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce version 5 vs 6, I use this:

```
var stripAttributes = function(html) {
  var tags = html.match(/(<\/?[\S][^>]*>)/gi);
  tags.forEach(function(tag){
    // Remove "class" attributes
    var noClass = tag.replace(/(class=".*?")|(class='.*?')|(class=[^\s>]*)/gi, '');

    // Remove "id" attributes
    var noID = noClass.replace(/(id=".*?")|(id='.*?')|(id=[^\s>]*)/gi, '');

    // Remove "data-" attributes
    var noData = noID.replace(/(data-.+?=".*?")|(data-.+?='.*?')|(data-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/gi, '');
    // Update html string
    html = html.replace(tag, noData);
  });
  return html;
};
```

And:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  toolbar: 'paste',
  paste_preprocess : (editor, args) => {
            console.log("before" , args.content);
            args.content  = stripAttributes(args.content);
            console.log("after" , args.content);
        },
});
```